# Prioritize build order with yarn workspaces and lerna

Tags: typescript, build, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have this big typescript project in a mono-repository using `yarn workspaces` and `lerna` with the following architecture:

```
repo
├── API
│   └── (GraphQL API)
├── Apps
│   └── (Front-end React Apps)
├── Libs
│   └── (Shared libraries)
└── Services
    └── (Back-end Services)
```

My `package.json` looks something like:

```
{
   ...
   "workspaces": [
        "API/**/*",
        "Apps/**/*",
        "Libs/**/*",
        "Services/**/*",
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
        "build": "lerna run build"
    }
    ...
}
```

My `lerna.json` looks like:

```
{
    "lerna": "2.11.0",
    "npmClient": "yarn",
    "useWorkspaces": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "Libs/**/*",
        "API/**/*",
        "Apps/**/*",
        "Services/**/*"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Now I need to build all the shared `Libs` before both `Apps` and `Services` because they have dependencies to it. But when I run `yarn build` and it triggers `lerna run build` it seems that it triggers the `build` process in a random(?) order, so it fails to build because the libraries "don't exist, yet".

Is there a way to set an order on how `lerna` triggers a build?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no prioritization in `lerna` so far.

Although here's what I do in several projects at the moment:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "lerna run build --ignore=libs-*",
  "prebuild": "lerna run build --scope=libs-*"
  ...
}
```

**Note: `prebuild` will run automatically so you don't need to call it explicitly**

One caveat here is you need to prefix all `Libs` package names with either something like `libs-module-name` as the example above or maybe a scope like `@my-org-libs/module-name` and call them with `@my-org-libs/*` instead.

Another solution would be calling each `Libs` package explicitly with multiple `--scope=package-name --scope=package-name-2` parameter in `prebuild`. But that might get quickly ugly if you have many modules under `Libs`.